# css multiple background position

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
html > body {
        background:url("https://www.carmignanospy.com/bgg.png"),url("https://www.carmignanospy.com/bgg.png"),url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/b6/d9/afb6d99af51006ae46e855d6b9796c51.jpg");
  background-position: 30px, right, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat, repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

I need set second image to the right, but with 30px margin.
How I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `right` specific your `<percentage> || <Length>`, but you must declare the second position.

For example:

```
  background-position: 30px, right 3em center, left top;
```